# Why is my submit event not being caught by jQuery in ASP.NET?

Tags: .net, asp.net, javascript, jquery

I wrote this on a simple ASP.NET page:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery("form").submit(function() {
   alert("kikoo");
   return false
  });
});
```

and when I submit (by clicking on a button, link, ...), I never see the alert box.

Is there something in asp.net page that "bypass" the submit (I think about the dopostback javascript method)

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Are there any javascript errors on the page that might keep the handler from being set up?

Comment: exactly where and when in the page does this block run?

Comment: I've run into the same issue with jQuery not capturing the submit event on an ASP.NET form, which I suspect is due to the _DoPostback architecture, as Pitming suggests. It's frustrating that no one here seems to have given this any serious thought.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the problem.

when i click on some button, they call a all javascript method that does form.submit. This is not caught by jQuery.

I'll correct the behaviour of my button and it'll work fine.

thanks all for help.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you are confused about the usage of the [jQuery submit()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/submit) function?

It sounds like you're expecting the alert dialog to happen on page load because you think the submit function is actually submitting your form.  But with the way you are using it, the submit() function is just attaching an event to your form so that when you actually **do** submit it, your function will run.

To actually trigger the submit from your code, you have to use submit() without any arguments like this:

```
$("form").submit();
```

Here's an expanded example, using Mike C's answer as the basis:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("form").submit(function() {
            alert("kikoo"); return false
        });
        // you could also chain this onto the end of the previous function
        $("form").submit();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form><input type="submit" /></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The OP explicitly mentions buttons activating the submit and the alert in the posted code is by way of an event handler.

Comment: annakata: sorry, but i don't undestand you answer. It seems my english level is too low.
Ryan: I'm no trying to submit the form. I'm trying to bind a behaviour when the form is submited.

Comment: My apologies.  I missed the "by clicking on a button" part.  I figure the information in my answer is still useful for people searching though, so I'll leave it up.

Comment: According to the original poster this is an ASP.NET application, so you need to have <form runat=server>..</form> and probably <asp:button .. /> to replicate this scenario

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I found that the do postback method override my handler (still don't understand why).

So here is what I did:
1. I declare my behaviour in a JS function

```
function MyBehaviour()
{...}
```

2. then i did a "classic" jQuery binding

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("form").submit(EncodeAllTxtControl);
});
```

3. then on each form, I had myu behaviour but keeping the already declared ones

```
jQuery("form").each(function() {
        var oldonSubmit = this.onsubmit;
        if (typeof oldonSubmit != 'function') {
            this.onsubmit = function() {
                MyBehaviour();
                return true;
            };
        }
        else
            this.onsubmit = function() {
                MyBehaviour();
                oldonSubmit();
                return true;
            };
    });
```

And this seems to work.